# Removed children seem to hide, not really go away

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

My dynamically added/removed components aren't really removed from DOM & Scoped Variables. What else could I consider/try?

I'm dynamically adding composite components on the server-side which works great, but when the user closes/removes a composite component via the embedded Primefaces panel, there are still big traces of the composite component and everything nested inside it. I'd like to ensure my close processing uses the "right mechanism" for fully removing everything.

**DOM:** When I chose "View Source" in the browser I see the added panel that was closed/removed (and its components).

**Scoped Variables:** When I look at the JSF Debug window, I see the scoped variables still include the closed/removed panel (and its components).

**Viewstate:** I assume the JSF viewstate still contains overhead of the closed/removed panel. The JSF Debug window isn't showing me state details.

It looks like my add/remove through getChildren() is all working properly when I debug through it. Maybe Ajax is part of the problem?!? See below that I'm using Ajax from the PrimeFaces panel menu choices. Or maybe I'm missing something big or obvious?

Dynamically adding components:

```
<h:form id="modelerForm">
        <h:selectOneMenu ... />
    <h:commandButton value="Add" actionListener="#{modelerController.onAddComponent}">
        <f:param name="topGroupId" value=":modelerForm:componentsPanel"/>
    </h:commandButton>

    <h1>Component</h1>
    <p:panelGrid id="componentsPanel"/>
</h:form>
```

and

```
public void onAddComponent(ActionEvent ev) {
[..]
    UIComponent wrapperComponent = WrapperLoader.loadWrapperCompositeComponent(wrapperId);
    CompositeComponentLoader.addAttribute(wrapperComponent, "chosenId", extComponentId);

    // Find topGroup
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    UIComponent topGroup = viewRoot.findComponent(topGroupId);

    topGroup.getChildren().add(wrapperComponent);
}
```

My composite component (w/panel):

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="chosenId" required="true" type="String"/>
    [...]
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <p:panel id="wrapperId_#{cc.attrs.chosenId}" toggleable="true" closable="true" widgetVar="wrapperVar_#{cc.attrs.chosenId}">
        <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{modelerController.onPanelClose}" update="@form"/>
        [... other Components ...]
    </p:panel>
</cc:implementation>
```

Close handler:

```
public void onPanelClose(CloseEvent event) {
    [...]

    // Find topGroup
    String wrapperId = getWrapperIdFor(extComponentId);
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    UIComponent topGroup = viewRoot.findComponent(topGroupId);
    UIComponent wrapper = topGroup.findComponent(wrapperId);
    topGroup.getChildren().remove(wrapper);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `inspect element` rather than `view source`. View source will (in every major browser) pull a new request of the page, and display that. The element inspector will show the actual current state of the DOM.

Comment: Will do. Btw, what is the etiquette/mechanism for posting full projects? As I try to post simpler code, I assume it would be better for someone to look at a simple project rather than a bunch of quotes from some files. I'm trying to get better about posting simple, clear & functional code for you experts. Thx.

Comment: There's some tips in the help center http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, the Chrome inspect has the DOM elements removed. Great tip. I'll have to watch for that in my simple examples too, and even have fiddler open to watch for web traffic on the View Source.